# Bidi bug in comments

Tags: bug, comments, hebrew

Comments that end with a right-to-left character and are posted by someone whose username starts with a right-to-left character mess up the display: the two characters mentioned are combined into one right-to-left interval which includes the comment/signature demarcation and its attendant dash.
[image: An example of this is on the linked-to question.]

I imagine this can be fixed by adding [U+200E](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) before the dash.

Comment: Very similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1322